# Which Liquids freeze when combined?

Tags: physical-chemistry, freezing, chemical-compounds

Are there any liquids (or liquid and solution) that when combined react to where they will freeze?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but you would probably receive better attention, information on the [chemistry stack exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

I don't know the answer regarding two liquids, but if you mix the two solids, **Barium Hydroxide Octahydrate** and **Ammonium Thiocyanate**, the solids will spontaneously fuse into a liquid with an endothermic reaction about -15 deg C, which will rapidly freeze any water. Demo on YouTube is [here](https://youtu.be/MyAzjSdc3Fc)

Take caution that ammonia gas is emanated during the reaction, so best done in a fume hood or well ventilated area.

Comment: Ice and salt do the same thing...

Comment: It is a good question, and it made me think of some binary phase diagrams I've seen of metals. Take a look at this Mg-Zn phase diagram ( https://www.researchgate.net/figure/237944094_fig2_Fig-2-Mg-Zn-binary-phase-diagram-redrawn-from-3 ), and note the two "troughs" that the liquid phase has at 30 at.% Zn and about 92 at.% Zn. If one were to have two vials of Mg-Al heated to about 400 ˚C, one with 30 at.%Zn and the other with 92 at.%Zn, and simultaneously pour both vials into a 400˚C crucible so that the two metal liquids mix together, then wouldn't the mixture freeze?

Comment: @Floris almost. With ice + NaCl a *physical* process that depresses the freezing point; described by Raoult's Law. And you need to start with ice at 0 deg C. The process I described is *chemical* and the two components can start at or above room temperature.

Comment: Sure - but this is a physics site and "combine" is not the same as "react".

Comment: @Floris - touche'